# Address Of (&) To Get Value From Symbol Table

Tags: c, assembly, linker

I have a question regarding how symbols are placed in the symbol table and then how you reference those symbols from within C.

So let's say I have a startup assembly file where some basic stuff is done before calling main(). One of the things it does is EXPORT a couple symbols which define the stack.

```
St_Length       EQU     0x00000400

                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
                EXPORT  St_Length
                EXPORT  ra_Stack
ra_Stack        SPACE   St_Length
```

Then in a source.c file in which I want to reference those symbols I have something like:

```
extern uint32_t St_Length; /* exported from asm.s */
void func( void )
{
    uint32_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < (uint32_t)(&St_Length); ++i)
        \\do something
}
```

This seems to work correctly, i.e. it will actually perform that loop 0x400 times. My question is why do I have to use the ampersand to get what seems to me like it should be the *value* of the symbol, not the *address of* the symbol?

NOTE: this is for an ARM Cortex-M3 using the toolchain provided with Keil.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** Here is the relevant portion of my symbol table from the generated map file:

```
 Global Symbols

    Symbol Name                              Value     Ov Type        Size  Object(Section)


    St_Length                               0x00000400   Number         0  startup_stm32f10x_md.o ABSOLUTE
```

Any explanation of the symbol table 'type' column would be very helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Because using `EQU` you have defined `St_Length` as a symbol for address `0x400`. To define it as a variable at some appropriate address, you should try something along the lines of:

```
St_Length DCD 0x400
```

(Put this in your data area.)

Comment: Why is it a symbol for *address* 0x400? Why not just a symbol for the numeric constant 0x400? From the ARM assembler manual "Use EQU to define constants. This is similar to the use of #define to define a constant in C." I don't want it to be an actual variable which takes up space in memory which is what DCD would achieve.

Comment: You can't do that in C. If you define the constant in another C module, such as `const int St_Length = 0x400;` that will also take up space. That your module is assembly, has no effect on this, unfortunately. `EQU` works inside your asm file because asm deals with addresses by default and you need to apply dereferencing to get at the values. C deals with values by default, and you need to apply the address-of operator to get addresses.

Comment: Can you point me to some reference for that? In the assembler manual http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489h/Caccddic.html it seems to imply otherwise. "abc EQU 2               ; assigns the value 2 to the symbol abc."

That seems wildly misleading if what you're saying is correct.